# Few Questions about PictureChooser Plugin

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm trying to use the `PictureChooser` plugin, specifically the `ChoosePictureFromLibrary` method, and I have a few questions.

1. Is it possible to show more than just .jpg? I'd like at least .png as well, though maybe other picture types too.
2. Is it possible not to resize chosen pictures? The `maxPixelDimension` parameter seems to always resize the image to that size.
3. Is it possible to have access to the original file name of the chosen picture?

Comment: there is a cool site that can this answer.. goolge... wow mind blowing!

Comment: ... quiet respect to Google for owning http://goolge.com

Answer (score 1):

The PictureChooser is really quite a small plugin - it really only has one small class per platform - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/v3.1/Plugins/Cirrious/PictureChooser

Because of this, the easiest route forwards for your specialist needs is probably to "branch" this small part of the code (by repo-forking or just by "copy and paste"). You should then find it straightforward to get hold of filenames, to avoid resizing, and to add any other features you need on the platforms you need to support.

---

If you create features that you think others may want, then mvx would love to see them open sourced back to the community - but that's not priority 1 - instead, the most important thing is making your app awesome and shipping it.